# Algorithm for filtering out duplicate letters and reassignment to available letters for menu alt keys

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a WinForms application with many menus, each menu has an average of 30 menu items. In any given menu there can be multiple words that start with the same letter.

Currently I use a simple method of creating an alt key mapping to each item by prepending an ampersand to the begging of each menu item.

I need to be able to detect a duplicate key mapping (starting letter) and reassign it to another character; on that hasn't been taken yet. The winning character would be the one closest to the begging of the word as possible.

### MENU Example

- **L**ist item
- **N**ew Window
- **S**ave Document
- **P**rint
- P**r**int Preview

A more ideal algorithm would be smart enough to look at the next word in the string, and have addition rules. If I could create a set of rules that emulates a menu such as this:

[image: FireFoxMenu]

I understand that fire fox most likely assigns their mappings manually - but I am trying to be constructively lazy.

Comment: You need to be careful to not change keyboard shortcuts when adding menu items. Your users'd hate you otherwise. =)

Comment: +1 Jens. Since I don't really think that each iteration of your program will spawn a couple of new random menus, it would probably be best if you took the time to define these in a configuration file somewhere. And this would also avoid the problem Jens has mentioned.

Comment: Excellent consideration - this has potential for changing the UX of the app as the menus evolve. This is definitely a downside I dont think the algorithm can account for with out some kind of memo or persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an average of 30 items, there's always going to be accelerator letters that are used more than once. And you certainly *don't* want an item's letter changing over multiple runs (or worse, multiple menu uses within the same run) of your program.

Why not just keep it simple and require each menu item to have a static 'accelerator letter' property?

Comment: Fortunately for both of us the requirement of keeping accelerator's the same throughout the lifetime of the application is paramount to the niceties of having an algorithm take care of it for me. So you are right; even though this sounds like a fun programming exercise - I will have to do it manually. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could treat this as an example of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm. In the language of the article, think of your menu item titles as workers. You want to assign each worker to a job, where a job is a letter from A-Z. The cost of assigning a worker to a letter (job) is the index of that letter in the menu item. This minimises the sum of the indexes, so if the first letters are all different the best solution is to use the first letter of each menu item.

Of course, you usually have more letters than menu items. You can get round this by inventing dummy menu items, charging the same amount for every possible assignment of letter to dummy menu item.

Comment: +1, perhaps an incremental improvement would be to make the cost `F(W, i, j) = i + abs(indexof(W, j))` where `i` is the index of the word `W` in the menu.

Comment: If you add the character code `j` to the cost, `F(W, i, j) = i + j + abs(indexof(W, j))`, it'll favor capital letters over lowercase letters.

Comment: +1 Very interesting idea - I will play around with this and see if I can construct a solution out of hungarian algorithm. I remember now studying this alogorithm in CSE but don't remember the context; I think it was some kind of path finding exercise... maybe that was AStar. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I really like ideas based on people providing some sort of score, and then having the program maximise that score. In theory, you could get better results than having somebody sit down and fiddle around by hand. However there is always the question of whether the user can understand the system well enough to write down a good score.

Answer (score 0):

For the impatient, like me, there's a very clean implementation of the Hungarian alogorithm  in C# [here](http://noldorin.com/blog/2009/09/hungarian-algorithm-in-csharp/) and here's a quick test rig to solve the OP's problem:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    test1()
End Sub

Sub test1()
    Dim menus() As String =
    {"File",
     "Fiddle",
     "Forest",
     "Fangle",
     "Edit",
     "Entity",
     "Entropy",
     "Eviction",
     "View",
     "Vixen",
     "Visible",
     "Window",
     "Wait",
     "What",
     "Tools",
     "Time",
     "Total",
     "Tea"}
    Dim items As Integer = menus.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim alphabet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Dim letters As Integer = alphabet.Length - 1
    Dim costs(items, letters) As Integer
    Dim cost As Integer
    Dim ch As String
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim longest As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To items
        cost = 1
        If menus(i).Length > longest Then
            longest = menus(i).Length
        End If
        For j = 0 To menus(i).Length - 1
            ch = menus(i).Substring(j, 1)
            o = alphabet.IndexOf(ch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            If costs(i, o) = 0 Then ' Don't overwrite when same letter more than once in word  
                costs(i, o) = cost
                cost += 2
            End If
        Next
        For j = 0 To letters
            If costs(i, j) = 0 Then
                costs(i, j) = 99
            End If
        Next
    Next
    longest += 1
    For r = 1 To 2
        Console.Write("".PadRight(longest))
        For i = 0 To letters
            Console.Write(alphabet.Substring(i, 1).PadLeft(3))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("")
        For i = 0 To items
            Console.Write(menus(i).PadRight(longest))
            For j = 0 To letters
                Console.Write(costs(i, j).ToString.PadLeft(3))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("")
        Next
        If r = 1 Then
            Dim h As New HungarianAlgorithm
            Dim result() As Integer
            result = h.FindAssignments(costs)
            Console.WriteLine("Answer:")
            For i = 0 To items
                Console.WriteLine(menus(i).PadRight(longest) & alphabet.Substring(result(i), 1))
            Next
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

End Module